# Render getTemplate() in nested foreach

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.3, knockoutjs

I am trying to update checkout page layout. What I want to do is to merge progress bar and checkout steps templates.

I have updated my **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/onepage.html** file and updated it like below.

```
<div class="opc-wrapper">
    <ol class="opc" id="checkoutSteps">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('steps') -->
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('progressBar') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko --> // Renders my progress bar template successfully.
                <!-- ko template: $parent.getTemplate() --><!-- /ko --> // To render step template, but not working
                <!-- ko template: $parentContext.getTemplate() --><!-- /ko --> // not working either
                <!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        <!--/ko-->
    </ol>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is to display navigator step first and after step, there will be the content for particular step.

I have tried using `$parent.getTemplate()` to call template of parent `foreach` but its not working. I have also tried assigning a variable to `getRegion('steps')` foreach and then use `step.getTemplate()` but its not working either.

Does anyone have idea how can I achieve this?